# Using array_diff to remove an item

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, array-difference

I am using `array_diff` to remove an item from an array... It works at removing `'field_home_slider'`, but the final `print render()` is outputting like 15 times. Am I missing something as to why the `print` would do that?

Can this be written a cleaner way? I want item `'field_home_slider'` removed from $page['content'];

```
$array_remove = array_diff($page['content'], array('field_home_slider'));
print render($array_remove);
```

**Original code**

```
print render($page['content']);
```

Comment: Dear acctman , Can you add which data contains in $page['content'] and its out put ?

Comment: @ShreyPrajapati `$page['content']` out puts all the content without anything being removed. I am using `array_diff` to filter it and remove item "field_home_slider". now when i out put `$array_remove` it is reprinting everything multiple times instead of just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
hide($page['content']['field_home_slider']);
print render($page['content']);
```

Here is the reference to the hide() function: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7